# Delete string from % in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have is 
  Excel book 1

```
    A
13%38 vs 44
13.64%38 vs 44
7.66%239 vs 222
```

And i require is in same excel sheet:

```
         A                 B
    13%38 vs 44           13
    13.64%38 vs 44        13.64
    7.66%239 vs 222       7.66
```

So basically i need to remove everything after `%` in each cell.

Can I achieve this with a formula in excel?

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 REPLACE(A1,FIND("%",A1),LEN(A1),"")
```

This will replace everything starting from the first occurrence of the percent symbol with a blank.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on Cell `B1`:

```
=MID(A1,1,FIND("%",A1,1)-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND("%",A1)-1)
```

to get the number before the percent symbol as text. The minus 1 is to exclude the percent symbol.

If you want to do any math on the result, embed it in the VALUE function

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND("%",A1)-1))
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest and therefore best way (just needs closing quotes after %) and using VALUE is a good hint.

Comment: IMHO yes. LEFT just does what it says on the tin whereas the fact that something like =REPLACE("abcde",5,1000,"xx") or even =REPLACE("abcde",1000,1000,"xx") is perfectly valid is (I think) an undocumented feature.